# AS3: creating a class with multiple and optional parameters?

Tags: class, parameters, actionscript-3

I'm creating a slideshow where each slide can have:
- a video or a still
- 1 audio track or many (up to 3)
- 1 button or many (up to 3)

I was thinking that each slide can be it's own object, and then I would pass the video, audio, buttons, etc., into it as parameters:

```
package 
{
    import flash.media.Video;

    public class Section
    {
        public function Section (video:Video, still:myPhotoClass, audiotrack:Sound, button:myButtonClass) {
            // can have video OR a still
            // can have 1 audio track or several
            // can have 1 button or more
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure how to go about approaching this since there can be multiples of certain items (audio, buttons) and also two items are sort-of-optional in the sense that there can be ONE or the OTHER (video/still).

For example, is this something that I should just avoid passing as parameters altogether, using a different approach (getters/setters, maybe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ["...(rest) parameter"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#..._%28rest%29_parameter)

```
private var _optionalParam:Array;  

public function exOptionalParam(arg1:Number, ...optionalParam) {    

  _optionalParam = optionalParam;

  trace(_optionalParam );  // [all the additional arguments]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see how this goes:

You can add all of your parameters and set them to null so they aren't needed, eg: video:Video = null, still:myPhotoClass = null, audiotrack1:Sound = null, audiotrack2:Sound, audiotrack3:null, button1... etc (Simple test worked)

Or just pass an array for the ones with multiple items, or a vector of the right type.